# jQuery Applications Pattern / Architecture

Tags: jquery

im looking best practices for jQuery application architecture.

This sample is working, but i think this is not a best way.

We have Kernel function (loads config, init sub-modules etc.) and Tabs dub-module as sample.

```
"use strict";
(function($, app, window) {

    app.kernel = function() {
        var self = this;
        app.tabs().init(); // init tabs sub-module
        return self;
    };

    app.tabs = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.init = function() {
            console.log('tabs function init');
        };
        return self;

    };

})(jQuery, window.SuperPuper || (window.SuperPuper = {}), window);

$(function() {
    new SuperPuper.kernel();
});
```

Founded some materials for:

1. [Using Inheritance Patterns to Organize Large jQuery Applications](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2010/02/using-inheritance-patterns-to-organize-large-jquery-applications/)
2. [How To Write Maintainable jQuery Applications](http://www.intelligiblebabble.com/how-to-write-maintainable-jquery-applications/)

Comment: to my understanding jquery is not really meant to build classes, however http://davidjs.com/2011/07/jquery-extend-inheritance/ and there is this plugin that seems to allow complex inheritance https://github.com/dfilatov/jquery-plugins/tree/master/src/jquery.inherit

Comment: When I do "single-page" applications with jQuery, I split application on functional blocks and then implement this blocks like jquery plugins. Plugins can communicate through plugin-method calls and custom events. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 0):

The best resource for jQuery patterns is by Addy Osmani who has compiled all the other material on the subject into an intelligible form:

> http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/